# Show 2 template in the same page/tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-template

I have a problem with ng-template.
Watching [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/hzxNa/1/), if I add in dropdown menù another option (ex template3.html), how can I show the first and the second template together?

HTML:

```
  <!-- template1.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    Content of template1.html
  </script>

  <!-- template2.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    Content of template2.html
  </script>


  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include src="template.url"></div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.templates =
    [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'}
    , { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'}
    , { name: 'template3.html', url: }//this must contain first and second template
    ];
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
}
```

Comment: can't you just create a third template that includes the other 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template that includes both of the others

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template3.html">
     <div ng-include src="'template1.html'"></div>
     <div ng-include src="'template2.html'"></div>
  </script>
```

JS

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.templates =
    [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html'}
    , { name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html'}
    , { name: 'template3.html', url: 'template3.html' }
    ];
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/207mcm0w/)**</kbd>